# how to extract particular data from logtable to another file using python?

Tags: javascript, python, linux, unix

Given a logtable and using python in unix i have to extract address data and time from the lines which contain STR or STRH to another file say f1 and the lines which contain MSR or MRS which further contain TTBR0 TTBR1 etc registers from those lines I have to extract registername data and address to another file say f2
the problem is that the logtable has data in this format

```
 255800 tic ES  (0000000000000424:79000020) O el3h:     STRH     w0,[x1,#0]
                ST 0000000000707000  ........ ........ ........ ....0001   S:0000707000
 255880 tic ES  (0000000000000428:d65f03c0) O el3h:     RET      
 265960 tic ES  (000000000000006c:940014fb) O el3h:     BL       {pc}+0x53ec ; 0x5458
                R X30 (AARCH64) 0000000000000070
 282920 tic ES  (0000000000005458:58000740) O el3h:     LDR      x0,{pc}+0xe8 ; 0x5540
                LD 0000000000005540  ........ ........ 00000000 00005340   S:0000005540
                R X0 (AARCH64) 0000000000005340
 292360 tic ES  (000000000000545c:58000761) O el3h:     LDR      x1,{pc}+0xec ; 0x5548
                LD 0000000000005540  00000000 00005458 ........ ........   S:0000005540
                R X1 (AARCH64) 0000000000005458
 298840 tic ES  (0000000000005460:cb000022) O el3h:     SUB      x2,x1,x0
                R X2 (AARCH64) 0000000000000118
 298840 tic ES  (0000000000005464:58000760) O el3h:     LDR      x0,{pc}+0xec ; 0x5550
                LD 0000000000005550  ........ ........ 00000000 011b1000   S:0000005550
                R X0 (AARCH64) 00000000011b1000
```

if i use the split method and index method to extract particular data then how can I extract the data and registername from the line next to the line containg STR or any other register 
m getting an error:
index no out of range if m trying to treat it like a single line

Comment: Please, reformat your question and put your code/data between  `  and ` e.g `some sample code`. That way your question will be much easier to read and understand.

Comment: see i know it may sound wierd but i cnt explain :P can i contact u smwhere else where it would be more easy for me to take ur help dont take me wrong